# Why is my program terminating with "Process exited with value 3221225477" while trying to store values in parallel arrays?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing, fgets

I'm writing a C program for an assignment that simulates a flight system. The file reading functions must fill parallel arrays from file, so I chose to read line by line with fgets. The read_flight function tokenizes each line and saves the tokens into the arrays passed by reference (up to 30 lines in a file). The printf statement after each save is just temporary code to verify that each variable was saved correctly. This code works for the first few lines, then the program terminates with return value 3221225477. From what I've been reading on this site, that code indicates a segmentation fault, but I can't for the life of me figure out why, as it's a different scenario from everyone else's that I've read.

If I reduce the size of the second dimension of the arrays passed to the read_flight function, the code runs a little farther for some reason before terminating.

My code is (with the termination occurring within the read_flight function):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

//Function signatures
int menu (void);
void modify_flight(void);
void modify_reservation(void);
void report(void);
void read_flight(int (*flightNumber)[30],
        char (*flightCityOrigin)[30][15],
        char (*flightCityDest)[30][15],
        char (*flightDate)[30][15],
        char (*flightTime)[30][10],
        int (*flightSeats)[30]);
void read_reservation(int (*resCode)[30],
        int (*flightNum)[30],
        char (*lName)[30][15],
        char (*fName)[30][15],
        char (*seatType)[30][8],
        double (*seatCost)[30]);
void exit_program(void);
void clear (void);

//Global variables
const char FLIGHT_FILE[] = "flightc.txt";   //File name of flights file
const char RES_FILE[] = "reservationc.txt"; //File name of reservation file

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int menuSel;    //Integer to store menu selection

    //Define parallel arrays to store information from flight file
    int flightNumber[30];
    char flightCityOrigin[30][15];
    char flightCityDest[30][15];
    char flightDate[30][15];
    char flightTime[30][10];
    int flightSeats[30];

    //Define parallel arrays to store info from reservation file
    int resCode[30];
    int flightNum[30];
    char lName[30][15];
    char fName[30][15];
    char seatType[30][8];
    double seatCost[30];

    //Call init functions
    read_flight(&flightNumber, &flightCityOrigin, &flightCityDest, &flightDate, &flightTime, &flightSeats);
    read_reservation(&resCode, &flightNum, &lName, &fName, &seatType, &seatCost);

    //Display menu in a loop until user chooses option 4 (exit system)
    do {
        //Call our Menu function to get our selection value
        menuSel = menu();

        //Call appropriate function as per menu selection
        switch (menuSel) {
            case 1:
                modify_flight();
                break;
            case 2:
                modify_reservation();
                break;
            case 3:
                report();
                break;  
        }

    } while (menuSel != 4);

    //Call exit program function
    exit_program();

    //Return with a normal exit code of 0
    return 0;
}

//This function prints the menu and returns the user's selection as an integer by value
int menu (void) {

    //Print menu
    printf("\n\tACME Airline System\n\n");
    printf("\n1.\tAdd/modify flight information");
    printf("\n2.\tAdd/modify reservation information");
    printf("\n3.\tReport section");
    printf("\n4.\tExit airline system\n\n");

    //Perform input in a do-while-loop for input validation
    int choice;

    do {
        printf("\n\tPlease make your selection >");
        scanf("%i", &choice);
        clear();
    } while (choice > 4 || choice < 1);

    return(choice);
}

//Stub
void modify_flight(void) {
    printf("\n(Inside modify flight function)\n");
}

//Stub
void modify_reservation(void) {
    printf("\n(Inside modify reservation function)\n");
}

//Stub
void report(void) {
    printf("\n(Inside report function)\n");
}

//Read flight file and parse lines into variables to fill the arrays passed by pointer
void read_flight(int (*flightNumber)[30],
        char (*flightCityOrigin)[30][15],
        char (*flightCityDest)[30][15],
        char (*flightDate)[30][15],
        char (*flightTime)[30][10],
        int (*flightSeats)[30]) {

    //Open flight file for reading
    FILE *flightFile;
    flightFile = fopen(FLIGHT_FILE, "r");

    if (flightFile) {

        char *token;    //Stores the current string token
        int i = 0;      //Counter variable for parallel arrays
        char line[60];  //Stores each line read with fgets()

        //Read file line by line, and parse each value into our parallel arrays. This
        //function assumes that the flight file is in the correct format for tokenizing,
        //I.E., that it contains the same number and format of tokens in each line.
        while (fgets(line, 60, flightFile)) {

            //Print line for testing
            printf("%s", line);


            //Get first token and store as flight number
            token = strtok(line, " ");
            *flightNumber[i] = atoi(token);

            //Test
            printf("\n%d", *flightNumber[i]);

            //Store second token as origin city
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            strcpy(*flightCityOrigin[i], token);

            //Test
            printf("\n%s", *flightCityOrigin[i]);

            //Store third token as destination city
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            strcpy(*flightCityDest[i], token);

            //Test
            printf("\n%s", *flightCityDest[i]);

            //Store fourth token as flight date
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            strcpy(*flightDate[i], token);

            //Test
            printf("\n%s", *flightDate[i]);

            //Store fifth token as flight time
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            strcpy(*flightTime[i], token);

            //Test
            printf("\n%s", *flightTime[i]);

            //Get sixth token and store as number of seats available
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            *flightSeats[i] = atoi(token);

            //Test
            printf("\n%d\n\n", *flightSeats[i]);

            //Increment counter for next line
            i++;
        }

        //Free resources
        fclose(flightFile);
    }
}

//Read reservation file and parse lines into variables to fill the arrays passed by pointer
void read_reservation(int (*resCode)[30],
        int (*flightNum)[30],
        char (*lName)[30][15],
        char (*fName)[30][15],
        char (*seatType)[30][8],
        double (*seatCost)[30]) {

    printf("\n(Inside read reservation function)\n");

}

//Stub
void exit_program(void) {
    printf("\n(Inside exit program function)\n");
}

//This function clears the input buffer after a scanf call to prevent input errors
void clear (void) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
}
```

The input file, flightc.txt, is as follows:

```
1234 Pittsburgh Phoenix 04/02/19 10:30am 108
4567 Boston New_York 04/03/19 18:10am 210
9876 Pittsburgh Seattle 04/04/19 1:30pm 110
8888 Chicago Pittsburgh 04/05/19 2:45pm 106
7777 Pittsburgh Miami 04/06/19 9:35am 116
2892 Las_Vegas New_York 04/07/19 8:10pm 107
4444 Pittsburgh San_Francisco 04/19/18 5:55pm 124
2222 Atlanta New_York 04/09/19 4:30pm 110
9281 Pittsburgh Seattle 04/11/19 2:15pm 216
1000 Pittsburgh Phoenix 04/12/19 3:25pm 150
```

It, theoretically, should populate these arrays then exit when the end of file is reached, but it's running for a few lines then terminating. The output looks like this:

```
1234 Pittsburgh Phoenix 04/02/19 10:30am 108

1234
Pittsburgh
Phoenix
04/02/19
10:30am
108

4567 Boston New_York 04/03/19 18:10am 210

4567
Boston
New_York
04/03/19
18:10am
210

9876 Pittsburgh Seattle 04/04/19 1:30pm 110

9876
Pittsburgh
Seattle
04/04/19
1:30pm
110

8888 Chicago Pittsburgh 04/05/19 2:45pm 106

8888
--------------------------------
Process exited after 0.8375 seconds with return value 3221225477
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Thank you all so much for any help you can offer me in tracking down why it suddenly stops working as planned. I'm a Java guy, not a C guy...

Comment: try to make a [mcve] instead of posting everything you wrote here. See also http://sscce.org/

Comment: One thing that'd help minimize how much code is here is if you define proper C structures to store your data instead of having a heap of unrelated but identically dimensioned arrays. Those method signatures are dizzying because of how much data you have ot pass in. Those should look like `read_flights(flight_t* flights)` or something like that where `flight_t` is a complete structure and that's a NULL terminated array of pointers.

Comment: Did you step through your code with a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again to watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Another C caveat is to not use fixed-length string buffers if you can avoid it. In Java you have a very robust String class. In C you don't, you must pay extremely close attention to buffer sizes and avoid overflowing them. Use `char*` for arbitrary character data and `malloc()` to size the buffers exactly as required.

Comment: Sorry for the copious code, this is my first post ever. I'll try stepping through now, I'll let you know what I get

Comment: Let me see what I come up with after using a struct and malloc(), I'll get back to you all in a short bit

Comment: There are some good resources out there on how and why to create short, self contained, and otherwise correct examples when asking about a problem you're having: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Changing my code to use structs instead of trying to pass all of those arrays worked, it fixed the problem! Thanks, tadman!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apart from the correct advice every one gave you of coming up with a short example, i took the time to dig into your code and found your first problem.

```
strcpy(*flightCityOrigin[i], token);
```

[] takes precedence over * and hence the index calculation happens first before * indirection which was not your intention. I could see in debug window that only your first token is copied in the 0th index of flightCityOrigin.

The solution is to specify the correct operator precedence as follows

```
strcpy((*flightCityOrigin)[i], token);
```

This applies to your subsequent arrays too.

Let me know if you still can't figure out the rest.

Comment: Additionally you didn't need to specify the additional char * for each array that you passed. They are already being passed by reference once you specify a single dimension's size and let the second one received as a pointer.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem as per tadman's suggestion to use structs instead of passing all of those arrays, and I think that addressed the problem you're talking about. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DaveWilliams in C declarations the syntax follows use. If you declare `int (*flightNumber)[30]`, it says that `(*flightNumber)[n]` is an `int`.

Comment: you are most welcome @DaveWilliams